Can I prove a limit this way?
I had this question in my test :
$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases} 
\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy} & \text{if } xy \neq 0 \\
1 & \text{if } xy = 0 
\end{cases}$
Check the continuity at the origin.
So to prove this it is sufficient to show that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x) = f(0,0)=1$
So, to do this, I let $xy=m$, and as $xy$ approaches $0$, $m$ approaches $0$.
Thus we have $\lim_{m \to 0} \frac{\sin(m)}{m}$ which turns out to be $1$.
Is this a right way to do it?

As $(x,y) \to 0$ so $xy = m \to 0$.

Yes, this is valid.

There is a big caveat, that the points of potential discontinuity are not limited to $(0,0)$ but every where $xy=0$, i.e. the $x$ and $y$ axes. But in taking $xy=m$, yes you are approaching all of the necessary points, since by continuity of $xy$ any path to any point must cross every level on the way to any of the destinations.
